# Combinatorics:No of solutions to an equation

Tags: combinatorics

Find the number of solutions to the equation $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 = 22$, where $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4$ and $x_5$ are non-negative integers, and $x_1+x_2 \leq 2$. (You may leave the answer as an expression consisting of binomial coefficients.)
So I tried solving it and I think we need to consider the cases when $x_1+x_2$ is equal to $2$; when $x_1+x_2$ is equal to $1$ and so on.

Comment: Your thought is correct.  You have three problems, one for each sum of $x1+x2$.  Are you familiar with stars and bars?  Search the site or Wikipedia for it.

Comment: Yes but the thing I want to know is is this using principle of inclusion and exclusion here.The answer is 24C2 +2*23C2 +3*22C2.I am not sure why they are multiplying by 2 and 3,Could you elaborate please.

Comment: I think I got it.Please let me know if my reasoning is correct.So

Comment: The answer you stated is correct.  It is obtained by treating the cases $x_1 + x_2 = 0$, $x_1  + x_2 = 1$, and $x_1 + x_2 = 2$ separately, then adding the results.